# Query where column value equals count MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 3 tables, "negocio" , "paquete" , "posts".

"negocio" has one "paquete", and "negocio" may have one or more "posts".

I want to bring all negocios that have the same amount of "posts" (that have as value on it's column "posts.tipo_post" the value "Post") records as the value on it's respective "paquete.no_posts"

I was doing something like this, but it returns me an empty set.

```
SELECT DISTINCT negocio.id, negocio.nombre FROM negocio
INNER JOIN posts ON negocio.id = posts.id_negocio
INNER JOIN paquete ON paquete.id_negocio = negocio.id
WHERE paquete.no_posts = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM negocio INNER JOIN posts
ON posts.id_negocio = negocio.id WHERE posts.tipo_post = 'Post' 
AND posts.estado_post = 'Disenador')
```

Comment: Have you tried running your inner query by itself?  I can't test it right now, but you may only be missing a GROUP BY

Comment: I have just tested it, and it counts all the records regardless of its "posts.id_negocio" value.

Comment: Thats because inQuery is being executed as a independent query. Try using alias.

Comment: I can't test it right now. See if this is the query you're trying to write. `SELECT n.id, n.nombre, COUNT(*) count FROM negocio n JOIN posts po ON po.id_negocio = n.id JOIN paquete pa ON pa.id_negocio = n.id WHERE p.tipo_post = 'Post' AND p.estado_post = 'Disenador' GROUP BY n.id HAVING count = pa.no_posts;`

Comment: @gunshot It throws me an error `Unknown column 'pa.no_posts' in 'having clause'`, and yes, the column exists...

Comment: @AarónGutiérrez Oops! Corrected query `SELECT n.id, n.nombre, COUNT(*) count, pa.no_posts noposts FROM negocio n JOIN posts po ON po.id_negocio = n.id JOIN paquete pa ON pa.id_negocio = n.id WHERE p.tipo_post = 'Post' AND p.estado_post = 'Disenador' GROUP BY n.id HAVING count = noposts;`

Comment: @gunshot And if I want also this condition: That counting those with `p.tipo_post = 'Gif'` equal the column `pa.no_gifs`.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @AarónGutiérrez Simple, Just replace with appropriate conditions in `WHERE` clause. Capture no_gifs field also in `SELECT` clause. Check if count is same in `HAVING` clause.

Comment: I ended up using this query:

`SELECT
 n.id,
 n.nombre,
 (
  SELECT
   count(1) AS total
  FROM
   posts p1
  WHERE
   p1.tipo_post = 'Post'
  AND p1.estado_post = 'Disenador'
  AND p1.id_negocio = n.id
 ) AS total_posts_actualmente,
 pa.no_posts AS numero_post_permitido,
 (
  SELECT
   count(1) AS total
  FROM
   posts p1
  WHERE
   p1.tipo_post = 'Gif'
  AND p1.estado_post = 'Disenador'
  AND p1.id_negocio = n.id
 ) AS total_gifs_actualmente,
 pa.no_gifs AS numero_gifs_permitido;`

Comment: `FROM
 negocio n
INNER JOIN paquete pa ON pa.id_negocio = n.id
HAVING total_gifs_actualmente = pa.no_gifs AND total_posts_actualmente = pa.no_posts;`

Comment: @AarónGutiérrez Cool! You can optimise it a lot. Above query has 2 InQueries in a loop, Which is not good. Check this `SELECT n.id, n.nombre, SUM(IF(p.tipo_post = 'Post', 1, 0)) total_posts, SUM(IF(p.tipo_post = 'Gif', 1, 0)) total_gifs, pa.no_posts, pa.no_gifs FROM negocio n JOIN posts po ON po.id_negocio = n.id JOIN paquete pa ON pa.id_negocio = n.id WHERE (p.tipo_post = 'Post' OR p.tipo_post = 'Gif') AND p.estado_post = 'Disenador' GROUP BY n.id HAVING total_posts = pa.no_posts AND total_gifs = pa.no_gifs;`

Comment: @gunshot It works great! Thanks, but, will the "GROUP BY" sentence won't give me any problems in some cases? I have tested it in 5 different cases and it works though...

Comment: @AarónGutiérrez Problems like? and cases like? As long as you want the counts against negocio.id, and use appropriate conditions in SELECT clause. It won't :P

Comment: @gunshot well, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try giving your count(*) table an alias

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM negocio N INNER JOIN posts P
ON P.id_negocio = N.id WHERE P.tipo_post = 'Post' 
AND P.estado_post = 'Disenador'
```